# MP4 file on hard drive plays fine but won't copy

Tags: hard-drive, file-transfer, copy

I have several MP4 files on an external hard drive that I am trying to transfer to a NAS.
Of several hundred files that were copied successfully, only 1 won't copy, it copies about 14% then the transfer freezes. I can click on the file and play it fine, it just won't copy. Any ideas what is wrong, esp when several other files worked fine?
The file in question is 1.52 GB on an NTFS formatted hard drive that holds 4 TB

Comment: If the file is very big and resides on a bad block, the harddisk may appear to hang, but might actually still work. Give it some time. You can try using other copy programs too. I often have great luck with TeraCopy in this kind of instance.

Comment: When you say 'it plays fine' have you tried playing it past the 14% mark?

Comment: @Tetsujin, yep can play the full movie all the way to the end with no issues, skips or  interruptions